# Can I extend the users current auto-renewable subscription expiration date

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I would like to implement a referral feature in an app that would add days to the user's current active subscription. Is there a way to do that using Apple's auto-renewable subscriptions?

Example

- A user has a 12-month subscription that will renew in 3 months for an additional 12 months
- The user refers a friend to use the app

Expected result

- The user has a 12-month subscription that will renew in 4 months for an additional 12 months

Answer (score 0):

To sum up:

NO.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/38689

Extend a Subscription Renewal Date API:

Compensation up to 90 days twice a year.
The extension period doesn’t count toward the one year of paid service when the App Store calculates the developer’s commission rate.

Apple Developer Documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/extend_a_subscription_renewal_date

AppStore Server API documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi

Apple subscriptions documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/